# MP Android chart draw all values

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using MP Android line chart. I got about 60 lines in chart. Problem is that when that much lines are drawn, mp android chart hide values above line.
When I zoom or when there is less lines i can see those values.

Is there some option to force drawing all values above lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the number of values at which the value texts will disappear using `setMaxVisibleValueCount` as indicated in the [`BarLineChartBase`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.0-beta1/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/BarLineChartBase.html) documentation:

> [`setMaxVisibleValueCount(int count)`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.0-beta1/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/BarLineChartBase.html#setMaxVisibleValueCount-int-): Sets the number of maximum visible drawn values on the chart. Only active when `setDrawValues()` is enabled.

So, in your case, the best you can do is set the max value count to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, like this:

```
mLineChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```